# Truffle test using multiple connections

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, private-blockchain, testing, connections

I am running a test which involves sending transactions to a smart contract from multiple nodes. Right now, I have seperate truffle folders in each node, with a test file that sends the transactions to the right contract. In addition, the first node's test file includes additional logic (apart from sending the transactions) that monitors the generated events from all transactions and makes calculations. From my understanding, there is no way to implement this logic in a single test file as truffle uses the config file to open only 1 connection and it is not possible to have multiple connections in 1 truffle instance?

Comment: Sounds about right AFAIK.

Comment: I wish I created my tests using web3 myself rather than using truffle test but I reckon it is too late for that at this point

Comment: Not really. Just a little bit of porting work is all it takes... You'll need to create the `web3 = new Web3(...)` instance given to you by Truffle "for free" yourself, but that's about it. If you're on Truffle 4.x or lower and your web3.js version is 1.x or higher, then you'll need to do some more work in adjusting your code. But all in all, it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: If it isn't too long, then you can post it here and ask specific questions on how to do the porting (don't forget to specify both your Truffle version and your Web3 version).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eUPrqZcZ
That's the code I used with 1 node sending all the transactions. I would have to modify it a bit so that they are send from 5 nodes. My issue with using different truffle tests is that I cannot get the individual transaction submission times into the array to be used in the calculations. As for changing it to using web3, what I am unsure about is how to get the contract instance ( as in truffle I use artifacts.require + the address of the contract on the chain).

Comment: "My issue with using different truffle tests is that I cannot get the individual transaction submission times into the array to be used in the calculations" - why don't you just pass as input a different to each test?

Comment: Yeah but then how can I get all the arrays into the first node's test in order to use them for the calculations?